# Eclipseのサーバービューについて

Tags: java, eclipse

JavaでWeb開発の勉強をしています。 Eclipseのサーバービューで「使用した可能なサーバーがありません」と出ています。しかし、Eclipseの画面左上のネコのマークを押すとTomcatは正常に起動できていますし、IEのアドレスバーにURLを入力して作ったソースの実行して上手くいっている感じです。
そこで質問なんですが特に、サーバービューでサーバーを定義しなくても問題はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

現状は問題ないかもしれませんが、なぜ問題ないのかを理解することが大事だと思いますのでそれについて記述します。

EclipseはOSGiと呼ばれる技術で機能拡張できるようになっています。Eclipseでは、機能拡張する部品のことをプラグインと呼んでいます。

Tomcatを操作できるプラグインは、主要なものが2つあります。

1. [Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP)](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)

   - Eclipse Foundation のプロジェクトとして開発されているWeb開発を支援するツール群。
2. [Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html)

   - Tomcatの起動・停止やEclipseプロジェクトのデプロイ・アンデプロイなどをEclipse上から操作できるようにする。

WTPに含まれるServer ToolsがTomcat pluginと競合する機能を持ちますが、どちらもTomcatの操作という面では、できることにほとんど違いはないと認識しています。

サーバビューはWTPの機能で、kazuさんが利用している"ネコのマーク"はおそらくTomcat pluginで追加されるツールバーのボタンのことでしょう。つまり、今はTomcat pluginだけを利用している状態と思われます。動作に問題が出ていないのであれば、現状は問題ないでしょう。

しかし、私個人の意見としてはWTPのServer tools(サーバビュー)を利用するようにしたほうが良いと考えます。理由は2つ。

1. WTPはTomcat以外のAPサーバを利用する場合でも同じ要領で操作できる
2. WTPはEclipseの公式プロジェクトであり、IBMやRedhat等のAPサーバを開発している企業が支援している

JavaでWeb開発の仕事をする場合は、Tomcat以外のAPサーバを利用する機会があると思います。その際にEclipseを使用するかはわかりませんが、慌てないためにも慣れておいて損はないのではないかと思います。

---

余談ですが、"サーバビュー"といった表現やTomcat pluginをご存じないのに利用しているようなので、もしかするとEclipseの日本語化＋幾つかのプラグインを同梱したPleiades All in Oneを利用しているのではないでしょうか。
Pleiadesには、長らくTomcat pluginが含まれていましたが、現時点での最新版(Pleiades All in One 4.6.0.v20160622)では、含まれなくなりました。

Answer (score 0):

問題ないです。
私もいつもその構成で使ってます。
イメージは、「サーバーを定義」の方はプラグイン内にtomcatを起動させてる。
tomcatボタンの方はプラグインからtomcatを起動させてる。
こんなイメージです。あくまでもイメージですが(笑)